# calling function of another class through its function address

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to call a function of another class through function's address.
I have two classes CA and CB

CA have a method like

```
void CA :: CreateList()
{
    m_pWindow = DEBUG_NEW CA;
    if(! m_pWindow ->Create(_T("CListsdbb"),NULL,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|LVS_ICON|LVS_SINGLESEL                          , CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, NULL))
    {
        TRACE0("Falied to create list window");
        return;
    }
}
```

m_pWindow is attribute of CA of CWnd* type.

I have another class CB. In which I am trying to call this function 
void CreateList();

Like

```
void CB :: OnBtn(void)
{
    &CA::CreateList;
    MessageBox(_T("Hello world"), _T("Information"),  MB_OK);
}
```

but function is not calling. CA is owner of CB in container ship.

Please can anybody help me out from this problem.

Comment: try `CA::CreateList();`

Comment: I tried it but not giving error non-static member reference must be relative to an object. And CreateList() is in public:

Comment: If CA is owner of CB, then try `((CA*)GetParent)->CreateList();`.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "CA is owner of CB in container ship."

Comment: CA is owner of CB in containership means, CA is parent of CB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you have doesn't call anything, it just gives the address of the function. A pointer to member function, and calling it, goes like this in C++:

```
void (CA::*func_pointer)() = &CA::CreateList;

CA a;
a->*func_pointer();
```

Yes the syntax is retarded, there was a time where I remembered the page in the Stroustrup on my desk where this functionality is discussed because I had to look it up so often (basically every time I used this).

But I digress - what I should mention though, is that in 2014 you really shouldn't be using this anymore; use a signal/slot that will abstract this away for you.

Furthermore, I'm not sure from your example how CB should get access to an instance of a CA nor what 'CA is owner of CB in container ship.' means.